# Error running wsgi application: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: django, wsgi, python-3.8, pythonanywhere

I am trying to host my local web app on pythonanywhere. [*Beginner to Django and web-development*]

I am facing the following error while launching the app:

```
Error running WSGI application
2021-04-26 21:46:32,020: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'
2021-04-26 21:46:32,020:   File "/var/www/username_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2021-04-26 21:46:32,020:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2021-04-26 21:46:32,020: 
2021-04-26 21:46:32,020:   File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/web-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2021-04-26 21:46:32,020:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2021-04-26 21:46:32,020: 
2021-04-26 21:46:32,020:   File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/web-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2021-04-26 21:46:32,021:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2021-04-26 21:46:32,021: 
2021-04-26 21:46:32,021:   File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/web-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
2021-04-26 21:46:32,021:     self._setup(name)
2021-04-26 21:46:32,021: 
2021-04-26 21:46:32,021:   File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/web-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
2021-04-26 21:46:32,021:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2021-04-26 21:46:32,021: 
2021-04-26 21:46:32,021:   File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/web-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
2021-04-26 21:46:32,021:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
```

File locations:

The settings.py file is located at:

```
/home/username/WebDev/Website/Django/MyApp/myapp/myapp
```

I have modified '/var/www/username_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py' file as:

```
"""
WSGI config for myapp project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/username/WebDev/Website/Django/MyApp/myapp")

os.environ('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I have looked at the similar question on stackoverflow but still cant figure out what is wrong at my end.

Any pointers/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is resolved.

The problem was that environ is not a function but a process parameter and hence, using it like below was the cause of the error.

```
os.environ('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')
```

I changed the code to:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
```

and the error was solved.

Answer (score 0):

From taking a look it looks like the folder structure is fine.

What you might need to do is add the module into your `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.

Or, if you're getting an import error or a module not found error for something that you believe is installed, then you've probably installed it into a version of Python or virtualenv that your code is not running in. If it's part of your code that is not being found, then your Python path is not set up so that it sees the module you're trying to import. See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your inputs. However, the error was not in the path rather the way the value was being set. I have posted the answer to this post.